# No Login Page when upgrading GitLab on Digital Ocean

Tags: gitlab, upgrade, digital-ocean

I just upgraded from `Gitlab EE 11.8.0` to `11.11.4`.
I was upgrading to fix an ACMEv1 error for letsencrypt.

I ran `$sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, which updated Gitlab to `12.5.3`
Upgrades ran without any errors.

I then ran `$sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`, again everything went fine.
But now I'm still getting the page that says, " Please log into your Droplet with SSH to configure the Gitlab installation."

How can I get the login page to load? I'm also hoping my git repositories are still on the server...?

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turning off `letsencrypt` seemed to fix the issue and gave me the loginpage.

Editing the file `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and setting the following:

```
letsencrypt['enable'] = false
```

I then ran `$sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and the sites login page was back up.
I was hoping to have an automatic renewal of the SSL cert, but it looks like I'll be just updating it manually via certbot.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by reseting the root password by

```
sudo gitlab-rake "gitlab:password:reset[root]”
```

The reset password command is documented in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/reset_user_password.html#reset-your-root-password